# order by date_modified

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp, sql-order-by

I have a mysql table with a column of date_modified and a timestamp set with a default value of the current timestamp. When I insert into the table I get a timestamp. How would one order by the latest timestamp when showing the records in a php script?

Comment: `... ORDER BY date_modified`?

Comment: I wonder if you try that: ORDER BY with ASC or DESC

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL query would use an [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html) statement. Then your PHP script can loop through them normally to display them in the proper order.

To show them in chronological order:

```
ORDER BY date_modified ASC
```

Most recent first:

```
ORDER BY date_modified DESC
```

Comment: `ASC` can be omitted as it is default anyway

Comment: True, but by placing it there it's clear that is the intend result and not a possible omission.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to correct you, but just add additional information :)